# Python random frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, frequency-distribution

This code returns a number between 0 and 2:

```
from random import randint

a = randint(0, 2)
print(a)
```

Each "option" has 33.3% frequency.

This code return a number between 0 and 2, too, but the "options" has following frequency:
0...50%
1...25%
2...25%

```
a = randint(0,1)
if a == 0:
    print(a) 
else:
    a = randint(1,2)
    print(a)
```

It's working, but if I have more options or more difficult frequencies, the code will be too long and messy. 
So the question is: Is there any way to make the code (shown upper) more smarter and simpler?

Comment: And if that duplicate target isn't adequate, there is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19871608/4996248). Versions of this question pop up fairly often.

Comment: Maybe `random.choice([0, 0, 1, 2])`