# Python weighted random number within range

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to write a function that will generate a weighted random number. Simply put, I have two ranges, and one of them falls within the other. In x% of the cases, the number should fall within the inner range, but in y%, it should be outside of that but within the outer range.

[Generating weighted random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871608/generating-weighted-random-numbers)
I found this question about weighted random numbers, but this results in a number picked from a list of options and not a random number within a range. Is it possible to do so?

This is only part of my actual problem though, since I will also need to consider the previously generated number and be within a certain range of that number. If this range falls within the inner range, this will obviously not present a problem, but if it overlaps the outer range, it becomes more complicated.

I am trying to build a simulator with fluctuating numbers that are typically within 'normal' range but not always, and since it's supposed to be data that evolves over time, the next number can't deviate from the previous number too much.

EDIT:
I have now tried to make it so that if the deviation around the previous number is within the inner range, it will take a 'normal' random number within that deviation range. If the deviation exceeds the inner range at either side, I use the percentage to determine if the number should fall within range or not. If not, it will pick a number in the outer range. As I decided the deviation range will be smaller than the inner range, it will never exceed the inner range on more than one side. This way it is possible to have the setup like Patrick Gartner suggested. I implemented it as follows:

```
def RNG_with_ranges(r1, r2, chance, dev, prev):
    if prev-dev >= r1[0] and prev+dev <= r1[1]:  # within inner range
        return random.randint(prev-dev, prev+dev)  # normal random, I stick with ints for now
    else:  # not entirely within inner range
        p = random.random()
        if p*100 <= chance:  # if we will get a number in the normal range
            if prev+dev < r1[0]:  # if we are further left from the inner range than our dev allows
                return r1[0]  # return to the border, but this should be improved
            elif prev-dev > r1[1]:  # if we are further right from the inner range than our dev allows
                return r1[1]  # return to the border, but this should be improved
            return random.randint(max(r1[0], prev - dev), min(r1[1], prev + dev))
        else:  # if we get an outer range value
            if prev-dev < r1[0]:  # if we are left of the inner range
                # take a number between the dev or outer range limit and the dev or inner range limit
                return random.randint(max(prev-dev, r2[0]), min(prev+dev, r1[0]))
            elif prev+dev > r1[1]:  # if we are right of the inner range
                # take a number between the dev or outer range limit and the dev or inner range limit
                return random.randint(max(prev-dev, r1[1]), min(prev+dev, r2[1]))
```

The remaining issue is that the percentage only comes into the play if we reach the border between the inner and outer range, so the actual percentage will be unpredictably lower than the given one.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some example. This look more like a "do my homeworks" than a real question.

Comment: I have no idea from the wording of your question whether you are talking about generating integer values or floats.  Also, are you assuming uniform likelihood within the sub-ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, simply calculate twice. My implementation chooses between two ranges, I leave the implementation of *choose smaller inner or bigger outer but not inside inner* to you:

```
import random

# this is a either/or implementation
def wrn(r1, r2, perc):
    """Takes two ranges (or other iterables) and an integer perc value. Draws a random
    number from r1 if a random.randint(1,100) is below or equal perc, else draws the 
    number from r2 and returns it."""
    assert 1<=perc<=100, "perc must be in the range of [1,100]"
    p = random.randint(1,100)
    

    # choose which range to use
    if p <= perc:
        return random.choice(r1)

    # to get something in the bigger range but not in the smaller included range
    # you might need to reroll the bigger range number multiple times
    # until your value is no longer in the smaller, included inner range

    return random.choice(r2)
    

r1 = range(1,11)
r2 = range(10,100)

for _ in range(10):
    print(wrn(r1,r2,50))
```

Output:

```
89   # r2
9    # r1
7
5
30   # r2
7    # r1
8
39   # r2
48
79
```

If you dislike redrawing for your version you can create a list with all numbers to choose from: `k = [[n for n in r1 if n not in r2]` and draw once - just make sure you do not call it with something like `range(1,10**20),range(2,3)` - that list a **huge**.

Comment: Should that maybe be `random.uniform()` (or better yet `random.random()` and use a probability between 0 and 1)?

Comment: @akx if you want to represent the percentage as float sure

Comment: Hmm ok, yeah I kinda looked at this before, you basically run through two rounds of random. However, if the ranges overlap, I'd think this gets quite inefficient, since, as you mentioned in the added comment, you have to retry until your result is no longer in the inner range.

Comment: @Valis Yep. You could also create a new iterable and draw from that, but that would take more memory instead of runtime - its a tradeof. if you have a range of 1...10000 and exclude 2...9998 you get lots of tries until you get a vali outer range number. See edit. You could always calculate how many numbers are left in your case and map those available to a range from 0 to that many, draw that randomly and recalculate which number you got .... and thats only a couple of the alternatives you can do

Comment: I see I would be back to using a list with possibilities here... In the end I want to be able to generate a float, so that's why I want to steer clear of that.

Comment: @VAsilis maybe put what youve got into your question by [edit]ing - maybe some other minds come up with better approaches